# How to split on any non-word character with 0 or more trailing and leading whitespace?

Tags: java

As the question states, how to form a regular expression so that it "splits" on everything that is a non-word character with 0 or more trailing or leading whitespace?

So:

```
String a= Hello. My name is "Jello" What is your name?
a.split("expression")
```

Becomes...

```
[Hello, My, name, is, Jello, What, is, your, name]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

```
a.split("\\W+")
```

as described in the [Javadoc for Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). - `\W` is any non-word character and `+` means "one or more".